# NIntegrating an algebric function

Tags: numerical-integration

I have an algebric function of the form:

```
0.400065/(1 - x)^2 + 0.0216295/((1 - x)^2 x) + (
 1.63367 x)/(1 - x)^2 - (2.05536 x^2)/(1 - x)^2
```

I want to integrate the above function numerically over the limits 0 and 1.

But since the integrand is divergent and 0 and 1, the result just blows up.
Is there any way to handle this issue?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you do `expr = Rationalize[...]` first, to remove the numerics, then you can get an exact antiderivative `antidv = Integrate[expr, x]`. Then with this: `Limit[antidv, x -> 1]` is `Indeterminate` and `Limit[antidv, x -> 0]` is `-Infinity` so it's divergent.

Comment: Yes! That's what I am trying to clarify. Is there any way to work around this issue?

Comment: No there is no way to work around: `Integrate[
 0.400065/(1 - x)^2 + 
  0.0216295/((1 - x)^2 x) + (1.63367 x)/(1 - x)^2 - (2.05536 x^2)/(1 -
       x)^2 , {x, 0, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True ]` gives `\[Infinity]`

Comment: You should never use float values with Integrate and NIntegrate, it is a horrible bug, but it is what it is. I suppose Wolfram wants to have the ability to operate on float values too and thus made it kinda buggy. The worst usual problem is making it complex when everything is not complex. Instead of 0.400065 use 400065/1000000.

Comment: @Валерий It is never a good idea to use machine-precision numbers in Integrate because it specifically targets symbolic integration and not numerical calculations. Further, the fact that NIntegrate (or any other numerical function) may sometimes return small imaginary parts as results of calculations that should otherwise have real output is typically a result of inescapable numerical errors. You can use `Chop` on those results, or take different approaches to control precision in your computations. Neither of these behaviors is a bug though.